# Switch-case and out parameter in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

```
string returnString;
switch(Type) {
    case 0: returnString = exampleFunction(foo0, out int exitCode); break;
    case 1: returnString = exampleFunction(foo1, out int exitCode); break;
    case 2: returnString = exampleFunction(foo2, out int exitCode); break;
}
```

When I write this code, VS displayed me an error that 'A local variable named or function named 'exitCode' is already defined in this scope' for line 4 and 5. So if I want to get more than two variables with different types from `exampleFunction`, what should I do? If I can't use `out` in the code, should I use tuple to get `returnString` and `exitCode` from the function?

Comment: From what I can see, due to inline declaration, exitCode has already been defined on line 3, what you can do is moving the declaration of exitCode outside of switch and let switch give it the output value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could declare `exitCode` variable before the `switch`. You should initialize it with some value or have `default` branch in you `switch`. Otherwise there is a flow by which `exitCode` will be uninitialized after the `switch`. Compiler will not pass this. Also don't forget a `break` after each `case`:

```
int exitCode = 0;
string returnString;

switch(Type) {
    case 0: returnString = exampleFunction(foo0, out exitCode); break;
    case 1: returnString = exampleFunction(foo1, out exitCode); break;
    case 2: returnString = exampleFunction(foo2, out exitCode); break;
}
```

But overall having a method returning two different values (one as return value and second as out parameter) is a bad practice. Consider having some simple class with those values as properties:

```
class SomeValue
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }
}

static SomeValue ExampleFunction(string input)
{
    return new SomeValue
    {
        Foo = input,
        Code = 1,
    };
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...

    SomeValue val = null;
    switch (Type)
    {
        case 0: val = ExampleFunction(foo0); break;
        case 1: val = ExampleFunction(foo1); break;
        case 2: val = ExampleFunction(foo2); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a method return two different values is not strictly a bad practice; consider any `TryParse` implementation, which returns the "exit code" (`true` if successful) and the strongly typed parse result as an `out` parameter.

Comment: Oh I forgot to put `break` after each `case` statements.. that was just a mistake copying the codes.  Defining the variable outside of the switch-case statement did a great job to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring `foo0`, `foo1`, and `foo2`, perhaps you should consider using an array, e.g. `foo[]`. This is usually a good idea whenever you see variable names with ascending numbers like that.

If you do it that way, the problem goes away, and you code is *much* shorter:

```
var returnString = exampleFunction(foo[Type], out int exitCode);
```

If it doesn't make sense within the problem domain for `foo0`, `foo1`, and `foo2` to live in an array (e.g. their individual names are important), you can still use a temporary array as a map:

```
var returnString = exampleFunction(
    new[] {foo0, foo1, foo2} [Type], 
    out int exitCode
);
```

Comment: Naaah.. sometimes I call same functions yet `Type` is different.. I thought about this way but not my case. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You should declare "exitCode" only for the first time

```
case 0: returnString = exampleFunction(foo0, out int exitCode); break;
case 1: returnString = exampleFunction(foo1, out exitCode); break;
case 2: returnString = exampleFunction(foo2, out exitCode); break;
```

Once you declare it "inline", it becomes local variable for that block.